How to make text and img in a div the same size
I am trying to create a div that contains an img and a text over the img. The text will be with different size depending on the case, so I want to automatically adjust the width of the img to cover the text.
What I tried so far is this:


/* Container holding the image and the text */

.cartContainer {
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Centered text */

.cartTextCentered {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: fit-content;
}

.cartImg {
  max-height: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, 0.1em);
  width: fit-content;
}
<div class="cartContainer">
  <img class="cartImg" src="imagePath">
  <div class="cartTextCentered">
    This is my text.
  </div>
</div>



I would greatly appreciate anyhelp on the topic.
Revised:
This is what I want to achieve:
enter image description here
And this is if I use background-image:
enter image description here

You can only really do this with a background-image but it's not really clear what this is supposed to look like. Is the image taller than the text? If so the problem will probably require javascript.

Yes, this really needs more clarity, as to how exactly you want this to behave. You say you want the image width to adapt to the text width, but then you already got  max-height: 1.5rem; for the image in your example there - so is this supposed to stretch the image then, if necessary, deviating from its aspect ratio?

If you put the image into .cartTextCentered, and position it absolute as well, this should be achievable with a regular img instead of a background image, too, I suppose. Perhaps involving object-fit, but that really depends on how exactly this is supposed to behave.

you can turn cartContainer into Flex container. You can apply image as background via Css. After defining ``inline-size``` for container. width of the image will be automatically adjusted according to text size. If you need to show bigger portion of the image you could use padding on the container. I hope this version fulfils your requirements and works as intended.


*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
} /* removing above code doesn't change behaviour */

/* Container holding the image and the text */
.cartContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  inline-size:max-content;
  border:0.5rem solid tomato; /* this is only for demo purposes */
  margin-block-end:2rem; /* Just to make some space between dvis*/
  background:url(https://via.assets.so/img.jpg?w=400&h=150&tc=blue&bg=#cecece) center/cover;
}

.cartTextCentered {
  color:#ffffff;
  display:inline; 
}

.big-text{
  font-size:3rem;
}

.container-1 {
  padding:4rem;
}
<div class="cartContainer container-1">
    <p class="cartTextCentered">This is my text.</p>
</div>

<div class="cartContainer">
   <p class="cartTextCentered">This is my text. When text is larger than container width also growth</p>
</div>

<div class="cartContainer">
   <p class="cartTextCentered big-text">This is my text. When font-size is larger container width also grow</p>
</div>




Unfortunately, this is not working either :( The image is cropped in the container box and the text is under the image and not in the image.

I just edited code snippet. Hope this version works for you

You can achieve dynamic font sizing based on container width using vw units (viewport width) or other relative units in combination with media queries or CSS calculations.


<style>
/* Container holding the image and the text */

.cartContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Wrapper for text and image to ensure correct sizing */

.cartTextWrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Centered text */

.cartTextCentered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1rem);
  /* Example dynamic font-size */
  padding: 0.2em;
  /* Adjust padding for readability */
}


/* Image styling */

.cartImg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Ensures image doesn't exceed container width */
  height: auto;
  /* Allows image to maintain aspect ratio */
}

</style>
<div class="cartContainer">
  <div class="cartTextWrapper">
    <div class="cartTextCentered">This is my text.</div>
    <img class="cartImg" src="/imagePath.jpg" alt="Image description">
  </div>
</div>




This is not what the OP wants. The image is supposed to adapt to the text length not the other way round.

With this code you just need to put what size of font you want and if you change the size of view the text will be always covering the image. So it is about the text length. I didnt undestand what you are saying, could you put a different code for i learn?

It's not about making the font size larger, it's about sizing the image to the width of the text string so the image width is 100% of the text but the image height adjusts. CSS can't do that AFAIK.

I have revised my question and added an image to show you what I want to achieve. Basically the text could be anything and I just want to resize the image to be as big as the text.
